# Выбор папки. C++. MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Как вызвать Dialog для выбора папки, не для файла, а именно для папки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034943/win32-select-directory-dialog-from-c-c

Comment: [IFileOpenDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834(v=vs.85).aspx) с опцией `FOS_PICKFOLDERS`.